# SWRevealviewcontroller nested ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a problem:
   I'm using `SWRevealviewcontroller` as a menu in my app. It's mobile shop application, there are `home screen`, `account screen`, `cart` and `others` in this menu. Account screen is a `controller with TableView`, it also has several options, like sign in, create account, and others. `SWrevealviewcontroller` works only for the first controller, other nested in this controller with table view can't see `revealviewcontroller`. When I'm using `"Show" segue` it appears, but when I'm using `SWRevealviewcontrollerPushController` it crashes

```
(I implemented manual trigerring and the error is, that viewController with table view doesn't recognize segue with ID )
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :) I set Show segue, and then change class to SWRevealViewControllerPushController. 
But I want to know why it doesn't work when i just pick SWRevealViewControllerPushController while creating segue?